# Voronoi formula for the symmetric $L$-function with level $N $

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, harmonic-analysis, l-functions

Sorry to disturb. Does any experts here know something upon the Voronoi type for the symmetric $L$-functions$$\sum_{n\le X} A_F(1,n)e\left ( \frac{an}{c}\right)=?$$
Here $F$ is a symmetric-lift of a $GL_2$ cusp form of square-free level $N$ (i.e., $F=\text{sym}^2 f$), and $A_F(1,n)$ is the $n$-th coefficient of the symmetric $L$-function $L(s,\text{sym}^2f)$. The denominator $c$ is co-prime with $N$ (i.e., $(c,N)=1$).

I checked F. Zhou's paper "The Voronoi formula on $GL(3)$ with ramification" at https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.10786. But I am not sure if his definition of the $GL_3$ cusp form on $\Gamma_{N}$ covers my case.

Note that in the paper of Buttcane Jack and Rizwanur Khan's “$L^4$-norms of Hecke newforms of large level'', the authors said it seems challengeable to give a Voronoi type for the symmetric $L$-functions with $(c,N)=1$ as in the present case.

If any expert here leans something upon this type of Voronoi formula, please guide some reference or share some your very valuable comments here.
Very grateful for your time.

Much obliged, and thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't exist in the literature.

Comment: @ Peter Humphries  Thanks Humphries. So maybe we are faced difficulties when doing Voronoi for $c$ being coprime with the level. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I also wonder why can't one deduce Voronoi by appealing to the functional equation for $L(s,\text{sym}^2f \otimes \chi)$ as the authors like Goldfeld and Li or Stephen and  Schmid did in the literature..

Answer (score 11):

**Edit:** This is the third update of my initial answer. It includes some more details requested by the OP in the comments as well as some general updates. I apologize for the many edits and the length.

As pointed out in the comments such a formula is not explicitly in the literature. However, it can be derived from a general Voronoi type formula due to A. Corbett. Let me try to shed some light on how to do this in the following. For simplicity I will treat the modified sum $$S_F(X) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{A_F(n,1)}{\vert n\vert}e\left(n\frac{a}{c}\right)W\left(\frac{n}{X}\right),$$ for a smooth function $W$ with compact support in $\mathbb{R}_+$. To derive this formula it will be useful to switch to the language of automorphic representations. So let us assume that $f$ and $F$ are newforms and let $\pi_f$ and $\Pi_F=\text{sym}^2(\pi_f)$ be the associated automorphic representations.

Before we can come to the summation formula in question we gather some preliminaries. Note that, because $N$ is square free and $f$ has trivial nebentypus, we know that $\pi_{f,p}=\text{St}$ is the Steinberg representation for all $p\mid N$. From this we can derive several useful facts. At the archimedean place we find that $\Pi_{F,\infty}$ has representation parameters $$\lambda=(2\nu,-2\nu,0) \text{ and } \delta=\begin{cases} (0,0,0) &\text{ in the Maa\ss\  case,}\\ (1,0,1) &\text{in the holomorphic case.}\end{cases} $$ In particular, $$ L_{\infty}(s,\Pi_{F,}) = \begin{cases}
    \Gamma_{\mathbb{R}}(s+2\nu)\Gamma_{\mathbb{R}}(s)\Gamma_{\mathbb{R}}(s-2\nu) &\text{ in the Maa\ss\  case,} \\ \Gamma_{\mathbb{C}}(s+2k-1)\Gamma_{\mathbb{R}}(s+1) &\text{ in the holomorphic case.}
\end{cases}$$ See for example Proposition~5.12 in ["Summation formulas, from Poisson and Voronoi to the present"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0304187). The associated gamma-quotient then is
\begin{equation}
    \gamma(s,\Pi_{F,\infty},\psi_{\infty}) = \epsilon(s,\Pi_{F,\infty},\psi_{\infty})\frac{L_{\infty}(1-s,\tilde{\Pi}_F)}{L_{\infty}(s,\Pi_F)}.\nonumber
\end{equation}

The computation at the finite places is slightly more involved. We start by mentioning that the Steinberg representation corresponds under the Local Langlands Correspondence to $\Vert \cdot \Vert^{-\frac{1}{2}}\otimes \text{sp}(2)$, where $\text{sp}(2)$ is the $2$-dimensional special representation of $W_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$. Further, using Artin reciprocity we can identify a character $\chi$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}$ with a character of $W_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$. The upshot is that, we can compute the $L$- and $\epsilon$-factors of $\chi \Pi_{F,p}$ on the Weil-Deligne side. Indeed we find that
\begin{equation}
    \left[\Vert \cdot \Vert^{-\frac{1}{2}}\otimes \text{sp}(2)\right]\otimes \left[\Vert \cdot \Vert^{-\frac{1}{2}}\otimes\text{sp}(2)\right] \cong 1 \oplus \left[ \Vert \cdot \Vert^{-1}\otimes\text{sp}(3)\right]. \nonumber
\end{equation}
From this we conclude that instead of computing the local factors of $\chi \Pi_{F,p}$ we can compute those of $\chi\Vert \cdot \Vert^{-1}\otimes \text{sp}(3)$ on the Weil-Deligne side of the Local Langlands Correspondence. According to ["Elliptic Curves and the Weil-Deligne group"]([https://math.berkeley.edu/~dyott/Elliptic](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Edyott/Elliptic) Curves and the Weil-Deligne Group.pdf) by D. E. Rohrlich we have that
\begin{multline}
    a(\chi \Pi_{F,p}) = \begin{cases}
        2 &\text{ if $\chi$ is unramified,}\\
        3a(\chi) &\text{ if $\chi$ is ramified,}
    \end{cases}, L(s,\Pi_{F,p}) = L(s+1,\chi) \\ \text{ and } \epsilon(\frac{1}{2},\chi\Pi_{F,p}) = \begin{cases}
        1 &\text{ if $\chi=1$,}\\ \epsilon(\frac{1}{2},\chi)^3 &\text{ if $\chi$ is unitary and ramified.}
    \end{cases} \nonumber
\end{multline}
(Here some clarification concerning the epsilon factors is necessary. We are always following Langlands convention and consider the canonical additive character with the corresponding self dual Haar measure as fixed and drop them from the notation.)

Our local computation implies the well known fact that the conductor of $\Pi_F$ is $N^2$. Further, we can write
\begin{multline}
    A_F(m,n)=A_F\left(\frac{m}{(m,N^{\infty})},\frac{n}{(n,N^{\infty})}\right) (mn,N^{\infty})\\ \cdot \prod_{p\mid N} W_{F,p}\left(\left(\begin{matrix} (mn,p^{\infty})&0&0\\0&(n,p^{\infty})&0\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right)\right), \nonumber 
\end{multline}
where $W_{F,p}$ denotes the (suitably normalised) Whittaker new vector of $\Pi_{F,p}$. The Fourier coefficients $A_F(m,d)$ depend only on unramified data of $\pi_F$. In particular we have the following well known relations:
\begin{equation*}
    A_F(m,1) = A_F(1,m) = \sum_{d^2\mid n} a_f(\frac{n^2}{d^4}) \text{ and } A_F(m,n) = \sum_{d\mid (m,n)}\mu(d)A_F(\frac{n}{d},1)A_F(\frac{m}{d},1),
\end{equation*}
for $(md,N)=1$. Knowing the local $L$-factor we can compute
\begin{multline}
    W_{F,p}\left(\left(\begin{matrix} p^{f_1+f_2} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & p^{f_2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &1\end{matrix}\right)\right) = p^{-f_1-f_2}s_{(f_1+f_2,f_2)}(p^{-1},0)W_{F,p}(1) \\= \begin{cases} p^{-2f_1}W_{F,p}(1) &\text{ if }f_2=0, \\
        0& \text{ if } f_2\neq 0.
    \end{cases} \nonumber
\end{multline}
This can be deduced from Theorem 4.1 in ["Whittaker functions associated to newforms of GL(n)"](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jmsj/1390600834) by M. Miyauchi.

These preliminaries show that the case of symmetric square lifts (of forms of square free level) is very special. We now turn towards developing the requested Voronoi formula. Sine our method is flexible enough we will start by working in greater generality. Let $\Pi$ be an automorphic representation for $\text{GL}_3(\mathbb{A})$ of level $Q$ containing the newform $G$ of character $\chi$. (In the setting above we have $\Pi=\Pi_F$, $G=F$, $\chi=1$ and $Q=N^2$.)

We now make the first step towards our summation formula. By applying Theorem~1.1 from A. Corbett's paper ["Voronoi summation for $\text{GL}_n$: collusion between level and modulus"](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/813900) with $\chi=1$, $c_2=1$, $\phi_{\infty}=W(\frac{\cdot}{X})$, $M=Q$, $l=1$, $q=c$ we get
\begin{multline}
    S_G(X) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{A_G(n,1)}{\vert n\vert}e\left(n\frac{a}{c}\right)W\left(\frac{n}{X}\right)\\
    =c\sum_{\substack{m,r\in\mathbb{Z}_{\neq 0},\\ (m,N)=1,\\ r\mid N^{\infty}}}\sum_{d\mid c}\text{KL}(\overline{aQL^3}r;m;c,1,d)\chi(\frac{md}{c})\frac{A_G(d,m)}{\vert md\vert} \\ 
    \cdot \mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{\infty}, \phi_{\infty}}\left(\frac{rmd^2}{c^3QL^3}\right)\cdot \prod_{p\mid N} \mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{p}}\left(\frac{rmd^2}{c^3QL^3}\right), \nonumber
\end{multline}
where $L$ is the largest square free integer dividing $Q$. Here $\text{KL}$ is a 2-dimensional Kloosterman sum defined by $$\text{KL}_2(x,y;\frac{c}{d})\colon =\text{KL}(x;y;c,1,d) = \sum_{\alpha\in \left(\mathbb{Z}/\frac{c}{d}\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}}e\left(-\frac{xd\alpha}{c}+\frac{y\overline{\alpha}}{c/d}\right)$$ and the function $\mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{\infty},\phi_{\infty}}(\cdot)$ is a Bessel-transform of $\phi_{\infty}$ given by
\begin{multline}
    \mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{\infty},\phi_{\infty}}(y) = \frac{1}{4\pi i}\sum_{r=0,1} \text{sgn}(y)^r\int_{(\sigma)}\gamma(1-s,\text{sgn}^r\Pi_{\infty},\psi_{\infty})\vert y\vert^{1-s}\int_0^{\infty}W(\frac{x}{X})\vert x\vert^{-1-s}dxds \\
    = \frac{1}{X} [\mathcal{H}_{\Pi_{\infty}} W] \left(\frac{y}{X}\right). \nonumber
\end{multline}
Here we have rewritten $\mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{\infty},\phi_{\infty}}$ in terms of the transform
\begin{equation}
    [\mathcal{H}_{\Pi_{\infty}} W](y) = \frac{1}{4\pi i}\sum_{r=0,1} \text{sgn}(y)^r\int_{(\sigma)}\gamma(1-s,\text{sgn}^r\Pi_{\infty},\psi_{\infty})\vert y\vert^{1-s}[\mathfrak{M}W](-s) ds, \label{C}
\end{equation}
where $[\mathfrak{M}W]$ is just the normal Mellin-transform of $W$.

The transforms $\mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{p},\phi_{p}}(\cdot)$ are $p$-adic versions of this Bessel transform. They are given by
\begin{multline}
    \mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{p},\phi_{p}}(y)= \frac{\log(p)}{2\pi} \sum_{\substack{\xi\colon F^{\times}\to S^1,\\ \xi(p)=1}}\xi(y)\int_{\sigma-i\frac{\pi}{\log(p)}}^{\sigma+i\frac{\pi}{\log(p)}}\epsilon(\frac{1}{2},\xi\Pi_{p})p^{a(\xi \Pi_{p})(s-\frac{1}{2})}\frac{L(s,\xi^{-1}\tilde{\Pi}_{p})}{L(1-s,\chi\Pi_{p})}\vert y \vert_p^{1-s} \\ \cdot \int_{\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}} \xi(x)\psi_p(x\frac{a}{c})W_{G,p}\left(\left(\begin{matrix}
        x&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right)\right)\vert x\vert_p^{-s}d^{\times}x ds. \label{D}
\end{multline}

We claim that
\begin{equation}    
    \int_{\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}} \xi(x)\psi_p(x\frac{a}{c})W_{G,p}\left(\left(\begin{matrix}
        x&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right)\right)\vert x\vert_p^{-s}d^{\times}x  = \begin{cases}
        L(1-s,\Pi_p)W_{G,p}(1) &\text{ if }\xi\equiv 1,\\
        0 &\text{ else.}
    \end{cases} \nonumber
\end{equation}
To see this we note that since $(c,N)=1$ we have $\psi_p(x\frac{a}{c})=1$ for $x\in \mathbb{Z}_p$. Then according to Lemma 2.2 in ["Voronoi summation for $\text{GL}_n$: collusion between level and modulus"](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/813900) we have
\begin{align}
    &\int_{\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}} \xi(x)\psi_p(x\frac{a}{c})W_{G,p}\left(\left(\begin{matrix}
        x&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right)\right)\vert x\vert_p^{-s}d^{\times}x  \nonumber \\
     &\quad = \int_{\mathbb{Z}_p\setminus \{ 0\}} \xi(x)W_{G,p}\left(\left(\begin{matrix}
        x&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right)\right)\vert x\vert_p^{-s}d^{\times}x \nonumber \\
     &\quad = \sum_{k\geq 0}\int_{\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}} \xi(p^kx)d^{\times}x \cdot W_{G,p}\left(\left(\begin{matrix}
        p^k&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right)\right)p^{sk}. \nonumber 
\end{align}
In the last step we have used that $W_{G,p}$ is right-invariant under the standard congruence subgroup. If $\xi$ is ramified, then the $x$-integral vanishes by orthogonality. Otherwise, if $\xi\equiv 1$, we can use the identity
\begin{equation}
    \int_{\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}} \xi(x)\psi_p(x\frac{a}{c})W_{G,p}\left(\left(\begin{matrix}
        x&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right)\right)\vert x\vert_p^{-s}d^{\times}x = Z(1-s,W_{G,p}), \nonumber
\end{equation}
which follows from the equation, above and apply Theorem~5.1 in ["Whittaker functions associated to newforms of GL(n)"](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jmsj/1390600834). (We use the notation $Z(s,W)$ as in loc. cit. for the local zeta integral.)

With this claim being established the Bessel-transform as given above takes the following nice form:
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{p},\phi_{p}}(y)= \epsilon(\frac{1}{2},\Pi_p)\frac{\log(p)}{2\pi}\int_{\sigma-i\frac{\pi}{\log(p)}}^{\sigma+i\frac{\pi}{\log(p)}}p^{a( \Pi_{p})(s-\frac{1}{2})}L(s,\tilde{\Pi}_{p})\vert y \vert_p^{1-s}ds\cdot W_{G,p}(1). \nonumber
\end{equation}
Writing $L(s,\tilde{\Pi}_p) = \sum_{k\geq 0} s_{(k,0)}(\tilde{\alpha})p^{-ks}$ we find
\begin{align}
    \mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{p},\phi_{p}}(y) &= \epsilon(\frac{1}{2},\Pi_p)\frac{\log(p)}{2\pi}\sum_{k\geq 0}s_{(k,0)}(\tilde{\alpha})\int_{\sigma-i\frac{\pi}{\log(p)}}^{\sigma+i\frac{\pi}{\log(p)}}p^{a( \Pi_{p})(s-\frac{1}{2})-ks}\vert y \vert_p^{1-s}ds\cdot W_{G,p}(1) \nonumber \\
    &= \delta_{v_p(y)\geq -a(\Pi_p)}\epsilon(\frac{1}{2},\Pi_p)\vert y \vert_p p^{-\frac{a(\Pi_p)}{2}} s_{(a(\Pi_p)+v_p(y))}(\tilde{\alpha})W_{G,p}(1). \nonumber
\end{align}
According to Theorem~4.1 from ["Whittaker functions associated to newforms of GL(n)"](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jmsj/1390600834) we have
\begin{equation}
    W_{\tilde{G},p}\left(\left(\begin{matrix} p^{a(\Pi_p)+v_p(y)} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right)\right) = p^{-v_p(y)-a(\Pi_p)}s_{(a(\Pi_p)+v_p(y))}(\tilde{\alpha})W_{\tilde{G},p}(1).\nonumber
\end{equation}
Thus we get
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{p},\phi_{p}}(y) = p^{\frac{a(\Pi_p)}{2}} \epsilon(\frac{1}{2},\Pi_p) W_{\tilde{G},p}\left(\left(\begin{matrix} p^{a(\Pi_p)+v_p(y)} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right)\right)\frac{W_{G,p}(1)}{W_{\tilde{G},p}(1)}. \nonumber
\end{equation}
(If $\Pi_p$ is self-dual we can replace $\tilde{G}$ by $G$ in the formula above. This applies in particular to $\Pi_p=\Pi_{F,p}$, where this can be checked more directly using the explicit computations from the beginning.)

We use the evaluation of $\mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{p},\phi_{p}}$ to explicate Corbett's formula as follows. Putting $y=\frac{rmd^2}{c^3QL^3}$ we observe that the condition $a(\Pi_p)+v_p(y)\geq 0$ becomes $v_p(\frac{r}{L^3})\geq 0$ (since $v_p(Q)=a(\Pi_p)$ and $(mdc,Q)=1$). The latter is nothing but the condition $L^3\mid r$. We get
\begin{multline}
    S_G(X) = \frac{cQ^{\frac{1}{2}}}{X} \cdot \left[\prod_{p\mid Q}\epsilon(\frac{1}{2},\Pi_p)\right]\cdot \sum_{\substack{(m,Q)=1,\\ L^3\mid r\mid Q^{\infty},\\ d\mid c}} \chi(\frac{md}{c})\frac{A_G(d,m)}{\vert md\vert}\text{KL}_2(\overline{aQL^3}r,m;\frac{c}{d})\\
    \cdot \left[\prod_{p\mid Q} W_{\tilde{G},p}\left(\left(\begin{matrix} p^{v_p(r/L^3)} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right)\right)\frac{W_{G,p}(1)}{W_{\tilde{G},p}(1)}  \right] \cdot  [\mathcal{H}_{\Pi_{\infty}}W]\left(\frac{rmd^2}{c^3QL^3X}\right). \nonumber
\end{multline}
The condition $L^3\mid r$ comes from the support of the local Whittaker functions. Indeed the denominator $L^3$ appears in a the first place due to a rough estimate of the $p$-adic Bessel-transforms. Our refined analysis of the case at hand has now revealed the true support. This allows us to shift the $r$-sum accordingly to get:
\begin{multline}
    S_G(X) = \frac{cQ^{\frac{1}{2}}}{X} \cdot \left[\prod_{p\mid Q}\epsilon(\frac{1}{2},\Pi_p)\right]\cdot \sum_{\substack{(m,Q)=1,\\ r\mid Q^{\infty}}}\sum_{d\mid c} \chi(\frac{md}{c})\frac{A_G(d,m)}{\vert md\vert}\text{KL}_2(\overline{aQ},rm;\frac{c}{d})\\
    \cdot \left[\prod_{p\mid Q} W_{\tilde{G},p}\left(\left(\begin{matrix} p^{v_p(r)} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right)\right)\frac{W_{G,p}(1)}{W_{\tilde{G},p}(1)}  \right] \cdot  [\mathcal{H}_{\Pi_{\infty}}W]\left(\frac{rmd^2}{c^3QX}\right). \nonumber
\end{multline}

We now specialise to the case $\Pi=\Pi_F$. (Actually we only use that in this case $\Pi_p$ is self-dual it is easy to obtain a more general formula from the discussion above.) First we write $Q=N^2$, $\epsilon(\frac{1}{2},\Pi_{F,p})=1$ and $\chi=1$ in the formula above. Further, self-duality allows us to write
\begin{equation}
    \frac{A_F(d,m)}{\vert md\vert }\left[\prod_{p\mid Q} W_{F,p}\left(\left(\begin{matrix} p^{v_p(r)} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right)\right)  \right] = \frac{A_F(d,mr)}{\vert mdr\vert }.\nonumber
\end{equation}
Thus the $m$-sum and the $r$-sum can be combined. Thus, we have proved the following result.

$\mathbf{Theorem}$: Let $F$ be a newform for $\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})$ underlying the symmetric square lift of a newform $f$ of square free level $N$ and trivial character. Further fix a smooth function $W$ of compact support and take $(c,Na)=1$ as well as $X\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Then we have
\begin{multline}
    \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{A_F(n,1)}{\vert n\vert}e\left(n\frac{a}{c}\right)W\left(\frac{n}{X}\right) \\ = \frac{cQ^{\frac{1}{2}}}{X} \cdot  \sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}_{\neq 0}}\sum_{d\mid c} \frac{A_F(d,m)}{\vert md\vert }\text{KL}_2(\overline{aQ},m;\frac{c}{d})
    \cdot  [\mathcal{H}_{\Pi_{\infty}}W]\left(\frac{md^2}{c^3QX}\right). \nonumber
\end{multline}
Here the Bessel transform $[\mathcal{H}_{\Pi_{\infty}}W]$ is defined above. We essentially recover the formula given in equation (2) of ["The Voronoi formula on $\text{GL}(3)$  with ramification"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.10786).

Let us mention that the formula provided by A. Corbett is very general and very flexible. Thus, along those lines it is possible to derive many more explicit Voronoi type formulae for $\text{GL}_n$ in particular one can generalize the approach presented above in several directions. In particular, the argument above gives an explicit Voronoi summation formula fo $\text{GL}_n$ in the $(c,Q)=1$ situation. However, for more complicated cases the computational overhead might be far bigger.

Let us finish off by making some remarks concerning a follow up question by the OP in the comments. Looking at the $\text{GL}_2$-case one observes that very convenient Voronoi formulae for sums $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} e(n\frac{a}{c})a_f(n)W(\frac{n}{X})$$ are available whenever $(c,N)=1$ or $N\mid c$. A for analytic purposes useful completely general formula was only recently found in ["Subconvexity for modular form $L$-functions in the $t$ aspect"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.01576). In particular the case $N=p^{2k}$ and $(N,c)=p^k$ is very hard. Returning to the $\text{GL}_3$-world we can say the following. The Voronoi formula for the sum $S_G(X)$ if $(c,Q)=1$ is discussed in this post (with a little more work one can derive an explicit formula for general $G$ dropping the self-duality assumption). The case $Q\mid c$ is covered in ["The Voronoi formula on $\text{GL}(3)$  with ramification"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.10786) (along the lines of this answer one can also derive the corresponding formula from A.Corbett's work). The case for general $c$ will be very difficult. It is covered by A. Corbett's work but the compute the local Bessel transforms promises to be very hard.

To illustrate this let us look at the following toy situation. Let $F$ be the symmetric-square lift of a newform $f$ of level $p$ and trivial character. Then $F$ has level $p^2$. We now take $c=c'p$ for $(c',p)=1$. (We are brief in details and translate everything straight away in the explicit situation at hand!) This hits exactly the hardest case possible. However, our advantage is that we have full information on $\Pi_{F,p}$ as discussed above. Applying A. Corbett's theorem once again we find
\begin{equation}    
    S(X) = \frac{c'}{X} \sum_{\substack{(m,p)=1,\\ r\mid p^{\infty}}}\sum_{d\mid c'} \text{KL}_2(\overline{ap^4}r,m;\frac{c'}{d}) \frac{A_F(d,m)}{\vert md\vert} [\mathcal{H}_FW] \left(\frac{rmd^2}{Xp^5c'^3} \right)\cdot \mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{F,p},\phi_p}\left(\frac{rmd^2}{p^5c'^3}\right).\label{A}
\end{equation}
The job is now to evaluate the $p$-adic Bessel transform. For simplicity we assume that $W_{F,p}(1)=1$. In this case we have
\begin{multline}
    \mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{p},\phi_{p}}(y)= \frac{\log(p)}{2\pi} \sum_{\substack{\xi\colon F^{\times}\to S^1,\\ \xi(p)=1}}\xi(y)\int_{\sigma-i\frac{\pi}{\log(p)}}^{\sigma+i\frac{\pi}{\log(p)}}\epsilon(\frac{1}{2},\xi\Pi_{p})p^{a(\xi \Pi_{p})(s-\frac{1}{2})}\frac{L(s,\xi^{-1}\tilde{\Pi}_{p})}{L(1-s,\chi\Pi_{p})}\vert y \vert_p^{1-s} \\ \cdot \int_{\mathbb{Z}_p\setminus \{0\}} \xi(x)\psi_p(x\frac{a}{c'p})\vert x\vert_p^{2-s}d^{\times}x ds. \nonumber
\end{multline}
The $x$-integral can be evaluated using Gau\ss\  sums. Indeed one gets
\begin{equation}    
    \int_{\mathbb{Z}_p\setminus \{0\}} \xi(x)\psi_p(x\frac{a}{c'p})\vert x\vert_p^{2-s}d^{\times}x = \begin{cases}
        -\frac{p}{p-1}+L(1-s,\Pi_{F,p}) &\text{ if  } \xi=1,\\
        (1-p^{-1})^{-1}p^{-\frac{1}{2}}\xi(\frac{c'}{a})\epsilon(\frac{1}{2},\xi^{-1}) &\text{ if }a(\xi)=1,\\
        0&\text{ else.}
    \end{cases} \nonumber
\end{equation}
We conclude that in this case the Bessel transform reads
\begin{multline}
    \mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{p},\phi_{p}}(y)=\frac{\log(p)}{2\pi} \int_{\sigma-i\frac{\pi}{\log(p)}}^{\sigma+i\frac{\pi}{\log(p)}} \bigg[p^{2s-1}L(s,\tilde{\Pi}_{F,p})-\frac{p^{2s}}{p-1}\frac{L(s,\tilde{\Pi}_{F,p})}{L(1-s,\Pi_{F,p})} \\ +\frac{p^{3s-1}}{p-1}\sum_{a(\xi)=1} \xi(-y\frac{c'}{a})\epsilon(\frac{1}{2},\xi)^2 \bigg] \vert y\vert^{1-s}ds.  \label{B}
\end{multline}
With enough will-power one can certainly go further in the evaluation of this expression but we stop at this point. Our goal was to highlight some of the difficulties that arise when the additive twist 'colludes' with the level and we hopefully succeeded.

Comment: Dear Windom Earle, deep thanks for so detailed and so impressive explanation! Much obliged. I have a naive question. Why the order of N, i.e. $N^5$, in  the summation formula for $S(X)$ in the middle part becomes $N^3$ in the last expression? I wander if you have taken $r=N^2$ or something. Thanks.

Comment: Dear Windom Earle, many thanks for warm-hearted guiding and timely reply. Great thanks.

Comment: Dear Windom, sorry to disturb. I am wander if the expression for $\mathcal{B}_{\prod_\infty}, \phi_\infty(y)=\fone{4\pi  } $

Comment: Dear Windom, sorry to disturb. I am wander if the expression for $\mathcal{B}_{ \prod_{F,\infty}  \phi_\infty } (y)$ should be $$\mathcal{B}_{ \prod_{F,\infty}  \phi_\infty }  (y)=\frac{1}{4\pi  i} \sum_{r=0,1} sgn (y)^r \int_{(\sigma)}   \gamma (1-s, sgn^r \prod\nolimits_{F,\infty, \phi_\infty}     )  |y|^{1-s} \int_0^\infty W(\frac{x}{X})|x|^{-s}\ud  x\ud s$$ by equ.  (26) in A. Corbett's paper. Here the gamma-factor $ \gamma (1-s, sgn^r \prod\nolimits_{F,\infty, \phi_\infty}     ) $ is $$\frac{L_{\infty}(1-s, \sgn ^r  \prod_F)}{L_{\infty}(s, \sgn ^r  \prod_F)}$$ by equ. (9) in A. Corbett's.

Comment: Sorry take long time to edit above comment. The function $\mathcal{B}_{ \prod_{F,\infty}  \phi_\infty } (y)$ should be the form $$ \frac{1}{4\pi  i}  \sum_{r=0,1}  sgn (y)^r \int_{(\sigma)}  \frac{ L_\infty (1+s, \prod_F) 
 } {L_\infty (-s, \prod_F)    }   |y|^{-s}  \widehat{W}(-s) ds, $$which is consistent with the gereral form of Bessel integral in the literature like D. Goldfeld, X. Li or S. D. Miller, W. Schmid's papers. The $\widehat{W}$ is the Mellin transform of $W$.

Comment: Dear Windom, sorry bother again and again. I am working on a problem involving the level aspect for symmetric $L$-function, i.e., we consider the $F=\text{sym}^ 2 f$, with $f$ being for simplicity the holomorphic form of prime level and trivial nebentypus. One key point is to desperately know the exact form of the Voronoi 
 for level aspect. There is No a explicit Voronoi on level aspect until you kindly pointed out the strategy, for which there should be highly appreciated in the Acknowledgements anyway, or list your name as the co-author.

Comment: Dear Windom, sorry to bother again. Could you please send you e-mail address to my mail-box (fhou@xaut.edu.cn), so that whether or not I can consult a detail in the post above? The comments box is so limited to write the expressions. Sorry if offended.

Comment: Dear Windom, sorry to disturb. Could you write the this explicit Voronoi in more details? This will help a lot noticing there is no any explicit form in current  literature for the time being?

Comment: I am wandering if the multiplier-factor in the final formula $\frac{c}{N^3}$ should be replaced by $cN/X$?  Notice that by Stirling’s formula the Bessel integral $\mathcal{B}_{\prod_{F,\infty},\phi_\infty}(y)$ can be truncated at $|y| \ll \frac{1} {X ^{1-\varepsilon}}$ satisfying that $x^j \mathcal{B}^{(j)}_{\prod_{F,\infty },\phi_\infty}(y) \ll_{k,\varepsilon} N^{\varepsilon}$ for any $j$.So morally one has the "\emph{balanced form}"$$\sum_{n\sim X} \frac{A(1,n)} {n}e(\frac{an}{c} ) \rightsquigarrow \frac{cN}{X}\sum_{n\sim\frac{c^3N^2}{X}}\frac{A(1,n)}{n}KL_2( \overline{ aN^2 },n;c),\tag{1}$$

Comment: so that (1) looks $$\sum_{n\sim X} \frac{A(1,n)} {\sqrt{n}}e(\frac{an}{c} ) \rightsquigarrow \sum_{n\sim\frac{c^3N^2}{X}}\frac{A(1,n)}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot \frac{KL_2( \overline{ aN^2 },n;c)}{\sqrt{c}}.$$

Comment: Dear Windom, yes you are right, the factor $X^{-1}$  defintely come from the definition of $\mathcal{B}_{\prod_{F,\infty} \phi_\infty}(y)$ by  Proposition~4.3 or more explicitly from the definition (3.1) in Kowalski-Ricotta's paper. Now I have a question/ How does the order of N, i.e. $^5$, in the summation formula for $()$ in the middle part becomes $N^2$ in the last expression again after re-editing the post? Did you just morally  multiply by $N^3$? Sorry for maybe stupid question.

Comment: @ Windom Earle Dear Windom, bother agian. Could shed some light on the Voronoi  formula for the type $$\sum_{n}\frac{A_F(1,n)}{|n|}e\left(\frac{an}{cN}\right)W(\frac{n}{X}), $$ where $F=\text{sym}^2 f$ with $f$ being prime level $N$ form, and here $(c,N)=1$? I wander if we have $$\sum_{n\sim X}\frac{A_F(1,n)}{n}e\left(\frac{an}{cN}\right)\sim  cN \sum_{n\sim \frac{c^3N^4}{X}}\frac{A_F(1,n)}{n}KL_2(\overline{aN^4},n;c)?$$ Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dear Fei, I have edited the answer once again including more details and addressing several things you pointed out in our discussion here. I don't derive an explicit formula answering the question in the last comment since this (in my opinion) would be outside the scope of this answer. However I should give enough hints so that you can complete the computations and arrive at an answer yourself.

Comment: Dear Windom, thanks for so impressive answer!!!

Comment: @WindomEarle  Really sorry to disturb. Two years ago we talked about the Voronoi formula for the symmetric-square lift of a newform of prime level $N$ and trivial character. (sorry I lost the account of username Fei on MO). I am writing to ask if you could add few details on the how to compute the integral "$ \int_{\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}} \xi(x)\psi_p(x\frac{a}{c})W_{G,p}...$" and that on how to "apply [Theorem~4.1 from [Whittaker functions associated to newforms of GL(n)] to express the symmetric Polynomial in terms of the Whittaker vector ...." to compute $\mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{p},\phi_{p}}(y)$.

Comment: @WindomEarle I wish could you would like to be as the co-author on recent paper I am writing, in which the Voronoi formula, that is, $\mathbf{Theorem}$ in the post is the core of the paper. Much obliged!!!

Comment: @WindomEarle I wish I could put the analysis in the post as the appendix, but it's really hard for me to clearly understand several steps to compute $\mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{p},\phi_{p}}(y)$. So I wish could you do me a favor. Many many thanks and merry Christmas!

Comment: @hofnumber I can happily add the required details to my answer (and also review the rest of it since it has been a while since I wrote it). I will do so as soon as possible but unfortunately I am not sure if I can do so before Christmas. (Don't worry about adding me as a co-author. There is no need for this. I am/was happy to help.)

Comment: @WindomEarle   Much obliged. I don't know how to say thanks! It's also my pleasure to ask you to be the co-author. When I complete the draft I wish I can, with your permission,  send you a copy; if it is meaningful, I wish I could have the pleasure to add your name. Dear Prof. Windom, yes, I need the rigorous proof to show the $\mathbf{Theorem}$, but I am not really so familiar with the adelic framework and  the representations. Thanks and thanks again!!

Comment: @hofnumber: I doubt that ["Windom Earle"](https://twinpeaks.fandom.com/wiki/Windom_Earle) is this user's real name.

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks for kindly pointing out.

Comment: @hofnumber: I have added some details. Note that the previous version was missing a $d\mid c$ sum in the main Theorem. I must have forgotten this somehow but it is corrected now. (Hopefully this does not destroy your application, sorry.) Also I do not remember anymore why the formula is not covered in F. Zhou's paper "The Voronoi formula on GL(3) with ramification" (more precisely equation (2) in loc. cit.).  I am leaving the answer roughly as it is anyway because I think it is good to know how the adelic Voronoi formulae due to Ichino-Templier and Corbett are translated to classical ones.

Comment: @WindomEarle Sorry to see the Update so late. Great thanks for so detailed and so long accounts for derivation. It's really spend lots of time to do so. Deeply thanks. However, I still have a few puzzles need some explanation. After computing the exact expression for $ \mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{p},\phi_{p}}(y)$ above, it's time to get the expression for $\Pi=\text{sym}^2 f$ (as you wrote "..With this at hand we can explicate our formula as follows.."); why when $y=\frac{rmd^2}{c^3QL^3}$, we may get the expression for $ W_{\tilde{G},p}$ with $p^{a(\Pi_p)+v_p(y)} $ replaced by $p^{v_p(r/L^3)}$?

Comment: @WindomEarle  Besides, I really wish to have the opportunity having your name on on my recent draft as a co-author. Could you tell me your E-mail by sending it to my mail-box: fhou@xaut.edu.cn ? It's really my great pleasure to do that.

Comment: @WindomEarle Many thanks for improving the post. Obviously, the poster is a top master who would't divulge the name. He/She deserves deeply respect and great gratitude. However, sorry, I still have a question: what $\psi_p(x\frac{a}{c})$ stands for in the formula for $\mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{p},\phi_{p}}$ after the paragraph "The transforms $\mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{p},\phi_{p}}(\cdot)$ are $p$-adic ....". I didn't know its exact definition, and why it equals to one when $(c,N)=1$？I guess maybe it stems form (19) in Corbett's paper. I wander if $\Pi_p$ here is just $\psi_p(x\frac{a}{c})W_{G,p}$?

Comment: I searched Corbett's paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.00716.pdf); the definition for additive character is given in (3). But I didn't know why we have $x\frac{a}{c}$ in $\mathcal{B}_{\Pi_{p},\phi_{p}}$ here. Also I guess \begin{equation}
 \int_{\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}} \xi(x)\psi_p(x\frac{a}{c})W_{G,p}\left(\left(\begin{matrix}
 x&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right)\right)\vert x\vert_p^{-s}d^{\times}x = Z(1-s,\Pi_p)W_{G,p}(1) \nonumber
\end{equation} not equaling to $Z(1-s,W_{G,p})$. Besides, it seems that there is no Lemma 2.2 in Corbett's paper. It's weird, the post mentioned Lemma 2.2.

Comment: Sorry, I  wander if  $\phi_{p} $ here is just $\psi_p(x\frac{a}{c})W_{G,p}$, not $\Pi_p$ in the comment next to last above.

Comment: @hofnumber Let me try to answer your latest question in the comments for now. First, the link in the answer should go to the published version of Corbett's paper. In the published version (American Journal of Mathematics 143 (5) October 2021) it is Lemma 2.2. In the arXiv version it is Lemma 2.1. Second, we apply Corbett's theorem with $\phi_p$ beeing the characteristic function of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ say. The $\Phi_p$ appearing in the Bessel transform is defined in Corbett's published paper equation (21) and (22). (This is (19) in Arxiv). This yields what is mentioned in your comment ...

Comment: ... Turning to $\psi_p$. This is the standard additive character of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. It is trivial (i.e. equals to 1) on $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and non-trivial on $p^{-1}\mathbb{Z}_p$. In particular, by the support property of $W_{G,p}$ we have that $W_{G,p}\left(\left(\begin{matrix} x&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right)\right)\neq 0$ only when $x\in\mathbb{Z}_p$. Since $p\mid N$ and $(c,N)=1$, we have $\frac{a}{c}\in \mathbb{Z}_p$. This means that $\psi_p(x\frac{a}{c})=1$ for $x\in\mathbb{Z}_p$. With this at hand one can directly establish that the integral equals $Z(1-s,W_{G,p})$ ...

Comment: ... The work of Miyauchi cited in the answer shows that, since $W_{G,p}$ is the Whittaker newform, one has the equality $Z(1-s,W_{G,p}) = L(1-s,\Pi_p)W_{G,p}(1)$. The factor $W_{G,p}(1)$ appears due to possible different normalizations of the Whittaker newform. Does this resolve your concerns in the integral evaluation?

Comment: @WindomEarle  Many many thanks. Every thing is clear! Please accept my very warmly warmly thanks for explanation along the time. I have concluded the argument above in my recent draft "Hybrid bounds for  $GL_3\times GL_1$ twisted $L$-functions at level aspect" with a deep appreciation. Thank you again for help with no any reward! My name is Fei Hou, it's a good enjoyment to learn the sophisticated insights form you, an excellent expert in number theory! Thanks again and again!!!

Comment: @WindomEarle   Hi there. Sorry to disturb again. Dear professor, I still have a puzzle needing some helps. As mentioned by Peter Humphries, the classical version for symmetric lift of the newform on $GL_2$ of prime level do not exist, but it seems that the work of Zhou, precisely (2) in the work, [The Voronoi formula on GL(3) with ramification] defined the Maass form for $\Gamma_0(N)$ on $GL_3$. I wander if the form $F=\text{sym}^2 f$ is one Maass form defined by Zhou?

Comment: .... So the biggest question is that the exact formula deduced laboriously in the {\bf{Theorem}} above can be directly followed from (2) in Zhou's work??

Comment: @WindomEarle  Dear professor,  I am also not clear that, regarding the Voronoi formula for symmetric lift on $GL_2$ of prime level $N$, if there is something different from the version worked by Zhou for the Maass forms defined for $\Gamma_0(N)$ on $GL_3$. Notice that the Maass form defined by Zhou (see Page 5 therein) seems not to be a cusp form, while $F=\text{sym}^2 f$ is. Great thanks for spending your time. Much obliged!

Comment: @WindomEarle Dear professor, sorry to spend your valuable time answering some might naive questions with no any reward. The thing is that recently the  referee in my  draft pointed out that Zhou's formula (2) appears to be used, not even deducing the  Voronoi formula again. But I feel that  Zhou's formula might not directly applied to the $\text{sym}^2f$ with $f$ being a newform of prime level on $GL_2$...

Comment: ...Also, I am  not familiar with the representation theory so much.  So, again, I post my puzzle on MO bothering some experts like you, wishing to get some help. I don't know how to say thanks for so much help from you, professor. Much obliged if some information can be given or some  reference can be guided. Great great thanks again and  again!!!

Comment: @hofnumber It is always good advice to listen to the referees suggestions. As already mentioned in the answer above I am not sure why Zhou's formula should not be applicable. (After appropriately inserting a testfunction.) I have left the answer as it is because it is a good example of how to apply Corbett's great result. Furthermore the argument should easily generalise to $GL_n$.

Comment: @WindomEarle You are  right!  However, I still don't understand if the definition  of  Maass form for the congruence subgroup $\Gamma_0(N^2)$ (see page 5 on the paper  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.10786.pdf) given by Zhou covers the classical form  $\text{sym}^2f$ of a typical $GL_2$ cusp form of level $N$??  If so, probably the formula (2) in Zhou's paper can be directly applied. Many thanks.

Comment: @hofnumber I don't see the issue. Zhou clearly states what properties of a Maass form are required.

Comment: @WindomEarle Dear professor, sorry to disturb again. How did it go? Last year, you spent you valuable time share with me how to derive the Voronoi formula for symmetric lift by appealing to Corbett's paper. Much obliged for all you have done. By the way, I wanna ask an extra question: dear professor, the argument you told me seems to work with arbitrary level $N$, not necessary the square-free level. Whether or not we can get the Voronoi formula for the level $N$ being a positive integer which just satisfies that $(N,c)=1$  in {\bf{Theorem}} above?

Comment: @WindomEarle Dear professor, I have anther request. Could you tell me you real name so that I can mention you in the Acknowledgments of my work which I contained the ideas you told me before ? Many many thanks. You may also can told me in the E-mail: fhou@xaut.edu.cn.  Thanks.