Voronoi formula on $\mathrm{GL}_4$ in the level aspect with ramification
$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Let $f$ be an automorphic form on $\GL_3$ for $\Gamma_0(p)$ with $p$ being a prime (see Bump or Goldfeld's books for definitions). Recall that, in this paper-"The Voronoi formula on $\GL(3)$ with ramification", Zhou has formulated that, for any integers $a,c$ satisfying $(a,c)=1$ with $p|c$, one roughly has the corresponding relation:
$$\sum _{n\sim X}{A_f(n,1)e\left(\frac{an}{c}\right)} \omega \left ({n} \right)    \leftrightsquigarrow  c \sum_{\substack{m_2\neq 0}} \sum_{m_1|c} 
 \frac{A_f(m_1,m_2)}{m_1|m_2|}  S(a, m_2;c/m_1) \mho \left ( \frac{m^2_1|m_2|X}{c^3}  ;\omega\right) .$$
Now, consider $F$ be an automorphic form on $\GL_4$ of level $p$. My question is: in the case of $p|c$, whether or not we have a similar formula like:
$$ (1) \quad 
\sum_{n\sim X}  A_{F}(n,1,1) 
 e \left( \frac{an}{c} \right)  
 \omega \left ({n} \right) \leftrightsquigarrow  c\sum_{d_1|c}\sum_{d_2|\frac{c}{d_1}}\sum_{m\neq 0} \frac{\overline{A_F(m, d_2,d_1)}}{|m|d_2d_1} {KL}_2(\overline{a}, m,c;(1,1) , (d_1,d_2) )\, \mho^\prime \left ( \frac{mXd^2_2 d^3_1}{c^4}  ;\omega\right),\; ?
$$
where the hyper-Kloosterman sum is defined as
$${KL}_2(n, m,c;(1,1),  (d_1,d_2))= \sideset{_{}^{}} {^{\ast}_{}}\sum\limits_{x_1 \bmod \frac{c}{d_1} } \,\,
\sideset{_{}^{}}{^{\ast}_{}}\sum\limits_{x_2 \bmod \frac{c}{d_1d_2} } e{\left (\frac{d_1 x_1 n}{c}+\frac{d_2\overline{x_1x_2}}{\frac{c}{d_1}}+\frac{{x_2}m}{ \frac{c}{d_1d_2}}\right )} .$$
Note that when the level is trivial, the formula above for $\GL_4$ is already known; see, for example, V. Chandee and X. Li's paper (The second moment of $\GL(4) \times \GL(2)$ $L$-functions at special points). Besides, in the special case where $(p,c)=1$, one has an analog for $\GL_4$ Maass form, which has a similar structure like Eqn. (2) in Zhou's above mentioned paper; see, for example, Andrew Corbett's paper. I still can not be sure what looks like for the Voronoi formula on $\GL(4)$ when $p|c$.
If any expert here knows something on this question, please show a guide or certain references.
Many many thanks in advance.

Corbett's paper deals with this particular situation (and much much more). Of course, one has to rewrite his adelic statement back into a classical statement.

@PeterHumphries Thanks, Peter, I will check this again. It seems that Corbett was more concerned about the co-prime situation, as it mentioned "...Of particular interest are those primes at which the level and
modulus are jointly ramified..." in the Abstract.

I think there is a translation error on your behalf: if the level and the modulus are jointly ramified, then they are not coprime.

@PeterHumphries Many thanks for pointing out this blur.

The assumption that f has prime level p greatly restricts the possibilities for the local component of the corresponding automorphic representation at p. This makes it relatively easy to work out how Corbett's formula looks explicitly in this case.

@WindomEarle  Great thanks for kindly guide, dear professor. Very deep thanks to you for telling me how to apply Corbett's formula to work out the symmetric-square lift case roughly two years ago in this post (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337721/voronoi-formula-for-the-symmetric-l-function-with-level-n?rq=1). As mentioned by Prof. Peter Humphries, Corbett's formula can solve this case; however, to explicitly translate into the classical formula looks a bit tough for me now.

@WindomEarle Dear professor, I want to consult you again:  in the case of $p|c$, if the Voronoi formula should be the same as that for trivial level case (i.e., p=1)? Since according to Eqn. (1) of Zhou's paper mentioned above, even the well-known Voronoi  in the ordinary $GL_2$ case, the level $p$ does not involve if $p|c$.  In other word, I wanna ask if the form (1) in this post should be true? Many thanks.

Computing the local transforms in Corbett's formula is not a problem. These give indeed the desired hyper Kloosterman sums. But arranging them correctly requires playing around with the Hecke relations at the (ramified place) p.

@WindomEarle Dear professor, many thanks for explanation.

@WindomEarle Dear professor, sorry to disturb, I want to ask you  whether or not we have the exact value for the local Whittaker functions at ramified place $p$ ? That is, when $p$ dividing the level $N$, say, of the form $F$, what looks like for  $$W_{F,p}\left(\left(\begin{matrix}p^k& & &\
&1& &\
&&1&\
&&&1
\end{matrix}\right)\right)$$ for positive integer $k$? In  other word, how about the Fourier coefficient $A_F(p^k,1,1,1)$ for $p|N$, upon recalling the relation between Fourier coefficients and Whittaker functions as shown in Definition 5.1 of Corbett's paper.

Up to scaling these are the Dirichlet coefficients of the local L-factor at p. This can be computed reasonably explicitly in the relevant case.

@WindomEarle Great thanks for help. Yes, you are right. Noting that Edgar Assing  and Abhishek Saha have referred what these are for the $GL_2$ case (see, e.g., Page 9 of this paper--Yet another GL2 subconvexity result). But, for more general $GL_n$ case, there does not seem to be a clear record in the reference.
